# Isomorphism over $\mathbb{Q}$ but not isomorphism in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Sorry for my bad English.

Is there example as follows?

$Let$ $K,L$ be subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $L\neq K$ as subfield of $\mathbb{C}$,
but $L\cong K$ as field (ignoring emmbding to $\mathbb{C}$) .

Comment: In fact you can take $K = \mathbb{C}$ and $L$ to be a copy of $\mathbb{C}$ properly embedded in itself!

Comment: There are plenty of examples, for example you can take $L$ to be a non-normal field extension of $\Bbb Q$ and $K$ a conjugate field of $L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any $x,y\in \mathbb{C}$ which are transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(x)\simeq \mathbb{Q}(y)$ are isomorphic to the field of rational fractions $\mathbb{Q}(X)$, but they are in general not equal.

Comment: (+1) If an explicit choice is preferred, then $x=e^{\sqrt2}$, $y=e^{\sqrt3}$ is one such. For [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) says that these $x,y$ are algebraically independent.

Comment: Hmm. Actually we can simply use $x=e$, $y=e^2$. Transcendence of $e$ implies that $e\notin \Bbb{Q}(e^2)$ :-)